# Need inputs in using nested "if" in awk

Tags: awk, nested-if

I have the below script which will help to display the memory values, however I would like to print a variable as VALUE_NUM as 1 if Buffer Memory < Free Memory else 0.

Please provide your inputs on how to achieve it.

```
    if [ $REPORT_MEMORY_FREE_AS_MEMORY_AVAILABLE -eq 1 ]
then
    free -m | awk -v OFS="" '
            NR==2 { MEM_TOTAL_MB = $2;
                    MEM_USED_MB = $3;
                    MEM_FREE_MB = $4;
                    MEM_BUFFER_MB = $6;
                    MEM_CACHED_MB = $7;
            }
            NR==3 {
                    MEM_CACHE_USED_MB = $3;
                    MEM_CACHE_FREE_MB = $4;

            }
            END {
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Total (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=", MEM_TOTAL_MB;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Used (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=", MEM_USED_MB;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Free (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=", MEM_FREE_MB;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Buffer (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=",MEM_BUFFER_MB;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Cache (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=",MEM_CACHED_MB;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|cache_Used (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=",MEM_CACHE_USED_MB;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|cache_Free (MB),aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=",MEM_CACHE_FREE_MB;

                    MEM_USED_PCT = int((MEM_USED_MB / MEM_TOTAL_MB) * 100);
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Used %,aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=", MEM_USED_PCT;
                    print "name=Hardware Resources_mod|Memory|Free %,aggregator=OBSERVATION,value=", 100 - MEM_USED_PCT;
            }
     '
```

Comment: Why "yaml" tag? Do you mean "awk" tag instead?

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve the requirement?